# What is the passive form of "we will let it pass"?

Tags: phrase-request, passive-voice

I have this sentence where I want to use the phrase [let [something] pass](https://www.google.ps/amp/s/www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/let-something-pass) in the passive form:

> Mentioning this topic casually may **get passed(?)**, but getting deep into it will only lead to conflicts and hard feelings.

If I translated what we use in my native language in such situations, it would be [get absorbed](https://www.google.ps/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/absorbed), but I found that it means a totally different thing of what "let it pass" mean.

So, what is the passive form of "let it pass? If there isn't, then is there a phrase that means the same thing of "let it pass" and in the passive form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try

- **They might let it pass** if you mention this topic casually, but getting deep into it will only lead to conflicts and hard feelings.
- **They might let it pass** if this topic is mentioned casually, ...

It's not quite the idiom of "letting it pass" (decline to remark on), more "pass" (be accepted):

- **It might pass** to mention this topic casually, but getting deep into it ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, jonathanjo. Is there a way to get rid of the subject as to not put assumptions that there actually are other people who think the same?

Comment: added a similar expression